# detect paste on text box - vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a text box and want to know if the data enter into is via pressing numeric keys or via a CTRL+V or via mouse right click.

Do not want to use windows message to process for paste/right click paste event.

Comment: Then you can't find out.

Comment: @Hans Passant: If i were to use windows messaging, how would i know which text box received the paste event?

Comment: How do you know which box' text was changed?  Same thing, every control has its own events and gets its own messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the KeyDown event to see whether Ctrl, then V was pressed (in two subsequent events).

You can use the MouseDown event to see whether the right mouse button was pressed.

You can use the KeyDown event to see if numeric keys were pressed.

If you use a flag for these three cases, then check it in the TextChanged event, you can determine where the text likely came from.